# perl match transition to php preg_match

Tags: php, perl, preg-match

I have this piece of programming written in perl:

```
$string = '[jkl][mno][ghi]';
$search = 'John';

if ($search =~ /$string/i) { 
  do....
```

How do I translate that into php ?

I tried with preg_match but obviously it has a different syntax.  Basically , the if statement above will search if any of the letters located in between [] brackets match $search ..

How can I do this in php while keeping the same $string / $search values ?

#### Update - php code

```
<?php 
$string = "dan" ; 
$search = "[def][abc][mno"; 
if (preg_match("/".$search."/i",$string)) {
  echo "found it"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: This won't work on codepad.org but works on my local pc:

Comment: <?php   $string = "dan" ; $search = "[def][abc][mno";   if (preg_match("/".$search."/i",$string)) { echo "found it"; } ?>

Comment: You can update your question body to make it easier to read. But from what I see in the comment, you're missing end `]` in `"[def][abc][mno"`

Answer (score 1):

Regexp syntax should be the same if you use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). The difference is how you specify options. The can look like this:

```
$string = '[jkl][mno][ghi]';
$search = 'John';

if (preg_match("/$string/i", $search)) { 
  do....
```

#### Update

In your PHP code looks like you're missing ending `]` in `$search = "[def][abc][mno";`. Should probably look like:

```
$string = "dan" ; 
$search = "[def][abc][mno]"; 
if (preg_match("/".$search."/i",$string)) {
  echo "found it"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should've [tried/read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) first.

```
$string = '[jkl][mno][ghi]';
$search = 'John';

if (preg_match('/' . $string . '/i', $search)) {
    do....
```

Comment: I tried the exact same thing as above, I got just this:  Warning: preg_match(): Internal pcre_fullinfo() error -3 on line 7

Comment: @Dan if you can provide exact PHP code you've tried this will be very helpful.

Comment: ok, looks like it has to do with php version. Doesnt work on codepad.org but works on my pc.